# A key is bound to a function or a key binds to a function?

Tags: word-usage

For example, I have a shortcut Ctrl-x that executes "Cut" action when press. Should I say "Ctrl-x is bound to Cut" or "Ctrl-x binds to Cut"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither.

You should say

> Cut is bound to ctrl-x